# PUPPET: Where could be the templatedir if its not in puppet.conf?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-dashboard, puppet-agent

I want to remove templatedir from the puppet conf so that there won't be a deprecation error. But its not under puppet.conf or anywhere else I guess. I've grepped for that line almost everywhere..

Comment: What is the deprecation error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

The `templatedir` deprecation is documented in [Puppet's reference page](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/deprecated_settings.html#templatedir).

You should look at the generated config:

```
$ puppet config print templatedir --section master
```

You will need to move tempalates to the module's `/templates` folder. For e.g. `modules/example/templates/`.